# Activate retry in firebase cloud function programmatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i'm deploying firebase cloud functions to listen on changes in our firestore via continuous deployment.

I can only find a way to activate retries [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries). Which goes contrary to our cd approach.

Looking at the normal [gcp cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--retry) the retry flag can be given when deploying. But i cannot find a similar option in the firebase-cli or the firebase-functions interface (2.1.0)

Any hints on how to solve this?
Carsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no similar option for deployment using the Firebase CLI.

This is something being worked on by the Firebase team, so stay tuned for updates.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable retries in Firebase Functions using GCloud Console, manually by hand. Programmatically retrying trigger-based functions was added in `firebase-functions` 3.10.0 (see [changelog](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v3.10.0) and associated [pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/482)).

Since it's not entirely obvious from the PR or the docs, here's a quick example of the syntax:

```js
export const myFirebaseFunc = functions
  .runWith({
    failurePolicy: {
      retry: {},
    },
    memory: '512MB',
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
  })
  .firestore.document('/path/to/some/doc')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
   /* do stuff */
 })
```

At the time of writing this, it looks like the failure policy is simply on or off. Thus, this is equivalent

```js
export const myFirebaseFunc = functions
  .runWith({
    failurePolicy: true,
    memory: '512MB',
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
  })
  .firestore.document('/path/to/some/doc')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
   /* do stuff */
 })
```

**Some caveats:**

- You'll also have to deploy with `--force`
- You can enable retries only on triggered functions, not http-called functions.
- It would be idiotic not to build in some safeguards. Retry policy maxes out at 7 days, and bills just like any other function invocation, so if you have some unhandled error, it could repeatedly run for a full week. You can use `context.eventTimestamp` to know when the first attempt roughly started.

Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries and make sure your function in idempotent.

It was also difficult to discover what to return to force a retry or avoid a retry.
**Triggered Firebase functions must return a Promise.** (See this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&feature=youtu.be&t=34))

A retry-enabled Firebase function will retry if:

- it returns a rejected promise
- throws an exception
- or the function times out

That means that if you run into an error that you know won't eventually resolve itself with a retry (i.e. you want to stop the function execution and not retry), you can return `Promise.resolve({message: 'some message'});`