# Retry on Firebase functions with pubsub

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using firebase functions with pubsub. The functions are invoked every time there is an incoming message (push)
I am looking at incorporating retry mechanism for the functions. The retry is not working. The sample function is shown below.

```
export const helloWorldWithRetry = functions
    .runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 300,
        memory: "512MB",
        vpcConnector: cloudFunctionOptions.connectors["abcd_data_connector"],
        vpcConnectorEgressSettings: "ALL_TRAFFIC",
        maxInstances: 1,
        failurePolicy: {
            retry: {},
        }
    })
    .region("asia-south1")
    .pubsub.topic("helloWorldPubSubWithRetry")
    .onPublish(async (message, context) => {

        console.log("----------- ATTEMPTING -------------")
        
        const eventAgeMs = Date.now() - Date.parse(context.timestamp);
        console.log(`The event timestamp is ${Date.parse(context.timestamp)} and eventAge is ${eventAgeMs}`)
        const eventMaxAgeMs = 60 * 1000;
        if (eventAgeMs > eventMaxAgeMs) {
            console.log(`Dropping event with age[ms]: ${eventAgeMs}`);
            return;
        }
        throw new Error("Error, Retry")
        
    });
```

Is there a possibility to use retry in these cases? The documentation says that the message is `ack` immediately on function invocation

Is putting the message back on queue or pull method the only logical way to achieve retries ?

Comment: Have you tried with `runWith({failurePolicy: true})` as mentioned in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#in_function_code)?

Answer (score 0):

The functions can be configured to retry the failures - [refer docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries).

And do this in the code -

```
functions.runWith({failurePolicy: true}).foo.onBar(myHandler);
```

So all you need to do is identify what kind of exceptions are re-triable and throw them from your function.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working when I am throwing the error.

Comment: Did you redeploy the function with --force? That is necessary. There are some more caveats mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606808/activate-retry-in-firebase-cloud-function-programmatically

Comment: I worked with Firebase long time ago but you should also try `failurePolicy: true` instead. And don't forget to redeploy with --force after every change in the Policy.